# How to make clang-format put braces on the same line as function body?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is it possible to configure clang-format so that it puts braces on the same line as function body, provided it fits within the column width. To put it into code:

```
// Provided this exceeds the column limit ...
const void* address() const noexcept { return &_data[0]; }

// ... I want it to be formatted like this ...
const void* address() const noexcept
{ return &_data[0]; }

// ... but all I can get is either this ...
const void* address() const noexcept
{
  return &_data[0];
}

// ... or this!
const void* address() const noexcept {
  return &_data[0];
}
```

Is this possible and, if not, why? Should I open a feature request?

Comment: You should open a **pull request** that implements the feature you want.  Sending a **feature request** will be unlikely to be implemented unless/until there is a person who wants the feature (e.g, you).  Welcome to the world of open source projects!  (Assuming the feature is already available.  I don't know how to [configure](https://clang-format-configurator.site/) for it.)

Comment: @ Eljay I would be happy to do that. But first I wanted to check if the feature is already there but I do not know how to configure for it. Also, somebody may have a clue which source files to edit, which functions to look for...

Comment: (I did not downvote.)  Above, I just wanted to comment about the second half — if the feature is not available (which I don't know if it is/isn't available), that filing a feature request is like asking Santa for a pony.  But making the feature and filing a pull request is far more valuable.